# App store not connecting on Mac through Vmware virtual machine?

Tags: ios, macos, mac-app-store, vmware-workstation

I setup mac OS X 10.7 on my window-7 machine through Vmware workstation version 11.1.2 and it's running good. I want to download and setup XCode for coding but i am unable to connect app store. It is not even sign in me. I tried all solution given in this [apple link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203811). Please anyone give me any solution. One more thing i also tried to login on apple developer site through my existing apple id but after i click on sign in it's not showing the next screen after login.

Comment: Does the VM have an Internet connection? Have you tested it using a browser?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes i am connected to internet.

Comment: @shyam002 Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @UtsavDusad  yes i resolved this issue by using this link https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-vmware-on-pc/

Comment: Thanks Shyam! I got it fixed too!! I used the method I have given in the answer and It is for Mac OSx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** This solution is specifically unix based systems.

*Check the serial number in **about us** in VM. If it is not there or it is 0. Then below solution will definitely fix your problem.*

VirtualBox does not by default make a serial number available to OS X guests. Of course OS X runs just fine inside VirtualBox running on a Mac even in that case. But due to the serial number being “0” the App Store and Server applications will not work.

The solution is to determine the serial number of the real Mac by opening About This Mac or running System Information. It is an alphanumeric string. On my Mac Pro 5,1 it begins with a letter and is 11 characters long.

In Terminal run the following command substituting the name of your VirtualBox virtual machine and your serial number (all one line):

```
VBoxManage setextradata “<your-vm-name>” VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial “<your-serial-number>“
```

**Make sure you remove the quotes while entering the above command.**

Starting up the machine after this change will then present a serial number that matches the base system and applications will function correctly.

This was tested on a Mac Pro 5,1 running 10.10.5 with VirtualBox 5.0.14. The guest was 10.11.3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VMware Fusion 8, Mac Mojave both host and guest. App store was loading web content correctly on host but nothing on guest (Cannot connect to App Store).

I fixed it by shutting down the guest, go to Fusion > Virtual Machine > Settings > Advanced > check the "Pass power status to VM" checkbox, Start the guest again, retry the App Store connection, and it successfully loads web content.

Apparently Apple's fog up a mirror test is whether or not the macbook has a battery or power.

Comment: Wow. This fixed my issue. The VM and Apple ID worked fine a month ago (use it for dev testing) and now had the problem where my Apple ID would not login stating "a problem connecting to the Apple ID server". Running VMWare Fusion Player 13.5.0 running macOS 12.7.1 as a vm on intel iMac 2020 (running 13.6).  No idea what changed, no upgrade to VMware or MacOS until issue came up. Checking the "Pass Power Status to VM" in VM setting as suggested above fixed the issue. Would not have believed it but after several hours in try anything mode, found this and it worked.

Comment: Note: AppleID login issues on virtual machines running on Apple Silicon Macs does not work due to a lack of support, as of this thread and acknowledged by Apple - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707682